# Can I add extra fields to the a Magento 2 static block?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, adminhtml, overrides, static-block

I'd like to add something similar to a category drop down to Magento 2's static block. Is this possible, if so can somebody set me off in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check below two files for adding custom field in Static Block section:

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml
vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_listing.xml
```

You can create new UI component xml file (view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml) in your module that contain the code like below:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="is_featured">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Featured</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_featured</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Above code is for creating toggle boolean button in cms block form. You need to check for dropdown and extend data provider class to provide category list. Also need to create set up script to craete column in static block table.